# JUnit Test error with embedded glassfish container

Tags: java, jdbc, junit, glassfish

I must admit this JUnit Test has been a nightmare till now, I have invested some days, searching the Internet but everything I tried did not work.
The Error I have is following:

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/sample__pm
```

The jdbc/sample__pm does not exist but the jdbc/sample in the persistance.xml does. 
As I said I have already searched for this problem but I cound not find a solution to the problem.

I guess the problem is with the pom.xml, but don't know how to fix it.

Thanks for any help

the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.maggioni</groupId>
<artifactId>SampleApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
        <version>10.10.2.0</version>    
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>SampleApp</finalName>
</build>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>
```

the source can also be found [here](https://github.com/kenparker/SampleApp)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after losing lot's of time I got it right. I now can run my tests with my connection pool.
This problem is resulted by series of small maven code generation bugs in Netbeans.

Bellow are a serie of steps for you to check

1 - Your pom.xml must have the path , plugin and dependencies configured for glassfish-embedded-static-shell,  as follow:

- Add in the properties at the top of your pom the path to your glassfish instalation folder(here is mine):

`<properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <glassfish.embedded-static-shell.jar>C:/Program Files/glassfish-4.0/glassfish/lib/embedded/glassfish-embedded-static-shell.jar</glassfish.embedded-static-shell.jar>
  </properties>`

- Add/check the plugin definition bellow(substitute mysql per maven in your case):
          `

  ```
  <build>
  ...
    <plugins>
      ...
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.embedded</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>4.0</version>

          <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.glassfish.main.common</groupId>
                  <artifactId>simple-glassfish-api</artifactId>
                  <version>4.1</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
                  <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-static-shell</artifactId>
                  <version>4.1</version>
                  <scope>system</scope>
                  <systemPath>${glassfish.embedded-static-shell.jar}</systemPath>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                  <version>5.1.28</version>
              </dependency>
          </dependencies>
          <configuration>
              <app>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</app>
              <port>8282</port>
              <contextRoot>${project.artifactId}</contextRoot>
              <foo>bar</foo>
          </configuration>

      </plugin>
    ...
    </plugins>
   ...
  </build>
  ```

`

2 - Your glassfish-resources... it's silly, but the jndi-name of your jdbc resource must have the prefix java:app/ so, add it as sample bellow(just the resource, the connection pool can have any name):
 
*Just remembering the name of your jdbc-resource in glassfish will not have the prefix java:app, e.g.: my jdbc-resource in glassfish is just ShrewdPCPool

3 - Third and the silliest, when deploying the embedded glassfish, the auto generated script of Netbeans doen't include /src/main/resources/setup in the class path, so, the simple solution is to make a copy of your glassfish-resources.xml para /src/main/resources/META-INF/ or if you are patient enough change the script.

Dont forget to clean, and after build with dependencies before you run your tests!